# How to remove variables from a MsgBox

Tags: vba, variables, if-statement

So What I'm trying to do is pass a bunch of variables into an If...then statement. If the variable returns true, then it gets "" which is used in another part of the code. If it returns false, then a different value will be printed in a message box.

Here's the problem. There are multiple variables and when each is printed in the message box, it is separated by lines. If one variable, say C, returns true, it will just be a blank spacer in the message box with the rest saying something. Basically, I'm trying to remove the variable and have it not be put into the message box. How could I go about doing that?

```
Set cellD = Selection.Find(What:="7/27/2013")
If cellD Is Nothing Then
    D = "7/27/2013, "
Else:
    D = ""
End If

If A = "" And B = "" And C = "" And D = "" Then
    MsgBox (Pass)

Else:
    If A = "" Then Set A = Nothing
    MsgBox ("Missing:" & vbNewLine & A & vbNewLine & B & vbNewLine & C & vbNewLine & D)
```

Comment: What is `A` here? - you test it like it's a String but then set it to Nothing like it's an object...  Kind of difficult to follow your code - maybe add a few more lines so your intent is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
Sub test()

Dim output As String

Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim D As String

If A <> "" Then output = A

If B <> "" Then
    If output = "" Then
        output = B
    Else
        output = output & vbNewLine & B
    End If
End If

If C <> "" Then
    If output = "" Then
        output = C
    Else
        output = output & vbNewLine & C
    End If
End If

If D <> "" Then
    If output = "" Then
        output = D
    Else
        output = output & vbNewLine & D
    End If
End If

If output <> "" Then
    MsgBox ("Missing: " & output)
Else
    MsgBox ("Pass")
End If

End Sub
```

There are other ways, but I think this is a good place for you to start (making an assumption on your VBA skill level).    I assumed A, B, and C are all strings, but you should dim those as appropriate for your situation.

Hope that gets you close!

Comment: @user3485595  Great, glad I could help.  It's typically customary to upvote and / or accept a solution if it solved your problem.  This lets people who have a similar question know that the answer was helpful.